# fish shell: how to append an element to an array

Tags: fish

I'm trying to append an element to an array.

What I tried is:

```
 for i in (seq 10)
            set children $children $line[$i]
 end
```

but that does not add a new element. It creates a single variable containing all of children then a space and $line[$i].

Comment: What you are doing is actually correct. Why do you believe it is wrong? `echo $children` _will_ show lists as space-separated, so try something like `string escape -- $children` instead.

Comment: What @faho said. Also `printf '|%s|\n' $children` or, if you're using a new enough version `set --show children`.

Comment: aah thank you guys. the problem was I echoed $children at the end which made it a single line. I solved it by using tr to replace spaces with newlines like so `echo $children | tr ' ' \n`

Answer (score 12):

Using fish version 2.7.1-1113-ge598cb23 (3.0 pre-alpha) you can use `set -a` (append) or `set -p` (prepend).

```sh
set -l array "tiny tim" bob
set -l children joe elias matt

echo $children
for i in (seq 2)
    set -a children $array[$i]
end
echo $children
```

Output:

```
joe elias matt
joe elias matt tiny tim bob
```

---

You could also use the string command which should work on most recent versions of fish.

```sh
set -l array "tiny tim" bob
set -l children joe elias matt

echo $children
for i in (seq 2)
    set children (string join " " $children $array[$i])
end
echo $children
```

Output:

```
joe elias matt
joe elias matt tiny tim bob
```

Comment: While this does give seemingly correct output, some inspection reveals that using the string command gives a single string rather than an array (i.e. echo $children[2] gives the empty string)

Comment: Note that @HackerBoss's comment about it not giving the expected output only applies to the second form; the `-a` switch works just fine.